# AngularJs compile a directive in another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-editable, angularjs-compile

in angular Js I have created a module of mine and trying to use a module xeditable (http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/). There is a directive in my module which I am trying to compile in a directive in xeditable but it stays the same (the edit panel does not show my control, in code it is still showing name of my directive).

This is the line in xediable where I think it should get compiled:

```
$compile(self.editorEl)($scope);
```

I thought it was due to dependency so I added the dependency of myApp into editable. Here is how is bootstrap angular:

```
angular.bootstrap($app, ['myApp' ,'xeditable']);
```

Here is how I register xeditable:

```
angular.module('xeditable', ['myApp'])
```

The code `$compile(self.editorEl)($scope);` does not set return value in anything. So does this mean that self.editorEl will be updated after compilation?

I am looking at right area or do you think the error is somewhere else? No exception is being thrown.

Comment: What is `self.editorEl`?

Comment: self.editorEl contains the html code that has to be compiled and shown in an editor panel. It has a div containing my directive and buttons

Comment: It's not already in the DOM, right? So you want to add it to an other element (`$element.append($compile(self.editorEl)($scope));`) before to be able to see anything, I guess.

Comment: i can see the buttons which are children of the div. My directive is also being rendered but like this <mydirect .. /> instead of <input type=text ... /> which means that link function of the directive was not called

Comment: Can we see the code calling `$compile`?

Comment: this is a very complex code which you can see at https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/blob/master/dist/js/xeditable.js . check out line # 543